# Can i share variable within instances of model plugin?

Tags: gazebo-model, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am spawning objects that fall into virtual bin. I created model plugin for objects, that reads their positions. From what i understand each plugin is running separately for each model a they don't share any variables.

My goal is to delete last XY spawned objects if one of them is outside of the bin. Is there any way that i can share for example boolean within all instances of plugin, so when one object is out, other objects are also aware of this?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24035/can-i-share-variable-within-instances-of-model-plugin?/) by [Boris94](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16899/boris94/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2019-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For this kind of functionality, I recommend you use a `WorldPlugin`, which has access to all objects at once.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris94](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16899/boris94/) on 2019-10-26**:
i thought this might be best solution, going to try it on monday, thanks